# How to change the screen size on button press in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I tried using Window.size (height,widht) and Config but it was not working with Screen Manager

Comment: provide a [mcve] and read [ask], As you ask, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Add a method (***on_enter*** or ***on_pre_enter***) in each screen and use ***Window.size*** as shown in the following example.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Main(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.size = (900, 600)


class Login(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.size = (400, 300)

    def check_password(self, instance, password):
        if password == "pwd":
            instance.current = "screen2"


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyScreenManager>:
    Main:
    Login:
        id: login
    Screen2:

<Main>:
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Label:
            text: "Hello"
        Button:
            text: "Go to Login Screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "screen1"
<Login>:
    name: "screen1"
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.6}
        rows: 3
        padding: 20

        Label:
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
            text:"Password:"
            font_size: 30
            halign: "center"
            valign: "middle"

        TextInput:
            id: password
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.06)
            cursor_blink: True
            font_size: 20
            multiline: False
            password: True

        Button:
            text: "Continue"
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.08)
            on_release:
                root.manager.ids.login.check_password(root.manager, password.text)

<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Label:
            text: "Hello"
        Button:
            text: "Go to screen 1"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "screen1"
```

### Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Login Screen]

Comment: Thank you so very much brother. I was unable to find any solution.

Comment: You are most wecome. Please remember to mark the question as answered by "Clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer"". Thank you.